# Can Anyone Help With This Error With Fetch Results?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can Anyone Help With This Error With Fetch Results?

I am getting error that says: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath Routine not found in entity '" at line `if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])` .

The Method:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"Routine == %@",theSelectedRoutine]];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entity `Exercise` does not have a property `Routine`. Most likely this is a case-mismatch. Properties should begin with a lowercase like `routine`.

It is also possible that there is no such entity as `Exercise`. Make sure that `entity` is not nil.

Comment: I am using the predicate to pull in all exercises for a particular instance of routine.  Based on my model, what should I put in the predicate then?

Comment: Likely you need to switch "Routine" to "routine". In any case make sure that the name of the property is the same here as in the model.